# Making a query on a table that has json field and postgresql database and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a table the has column that contains a `json` field and `postgresql` as database storage containing this example:

```
{"wants_newsletter": "true", "favorite_color": "red"}
```

If I query on laravel like:

```
$model = Model::where('column->favorite_color', 'red')->first();
```

I can get the row successfully and now can do like

```
$id = $model->id;
```

But when on the same column has this kind of `json` structure

```
{"wants_newsletter": ["true"], "favorite_color": ["red","blue"]}
```

If I query on laravel like:

```
$model = Model::where('column->favorite_color[0]', 'red')->first();
```

I get `$model` that is null, which mean I did not fetch a row.

How to do it in laravel?

My resources find when searching are these:
[How can I make query where json column in the laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408491/how-can-i-make-query-where-json-column-in-the-laravel)
https://mattstauffer.com/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
->whereJsonContains('column->favorite_color', 'red')->first();
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses